# How to push data into an object in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am still learning things. Here I am trying to send data as an object to my end user. I succeeded in sending it as an array but failing to send as an object can you help me here, please.

I need data as an object data{}. This is in nodeJs.

```
let data = [];
students.map(student => {
data.push({
Name: payload.name,
stdId: payload.Id
});
});
```

Comment: arrays are objects. why would you need an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only return an object and map will by itself will create & return an array of objects

```
let data = students.map(student => {
  return {
    Name: payload.name,
    stdId: payload.Id
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), you can simply use it to return the newly created object.

```
let data = students.map(student => ({
    Name: payload.name,
    stdId: payload.Id
}));
```